# Need a service to handle multiple connections to 1 database

Tags: asp.net, wcf, sql-server-2008, windows-services

I have a SQL Server database which serves multiple ASP.NET web applications. They each have their own `SiteID` to distinguish the data.

I recently realised that it isn't good practice to have multiple applications accessing one database directly and decided I would implement a service to handle all database connections.

All the web applications and database sit on the same windows 2008 server.

I want to know what kind of service is best for this functionality. web service or windows service? In a previous job they seemed to have a windows service that ran on the server, what are the advantages of this over a web service?

Comment: Since they are web applications, a web service make a lot of sense over a windows service. You know, because they both have "web" in them.

Comment: Any need for the sarcasm? I asked because I have seen a very successful set up using a windows service on windows server 2008 for this very purpose.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You don't need either if you are simply moving a web application to another machine.

Comment: You don't need a service to integrate your web applications - it only would make sense if you need to provide an API for (mobile) apps or something the like.

Comment: How did the window service work?  Was it hosting web services?

Comment: That's not entirely sarcasm. I just don't see why you would want to put a dependency on a windows service from a web application. You would have to use something awful like Remoting or sockets, right? Why not use technology from the same stack? I'm just a web developer though, so maybe others will disagree.

Comment: @Maciej I have built a framework to create many similar web application. I have 1 database that serves these many web applications. I wasn't sure whether a service should sit between the web applications and the database to handle requests.

Comment: How are you currently connecting to the database? Are you trying to move the web application to another machine?

Comment: I'm not moving the web app anywhere (apart from to the live server when it goes live). I am connecting to the data through a simple Connection Class with a specified connection string.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions; I'm just trying to understand what your current situation is. Do you have a separation between the data access classes and the business logic classes? Are they in separate assemblies?  Perhaps it would be easier if you edited your question and added some details about how your current solution is structured.

Answer (score 1):

While it's certainly ok to have multiple applications accessing one database, I think what you mean is you are trying to avoid duplicating all your data access and business logic in multiple web sites. In other words, you would rather have a centralized service where you can update all the applications at once.

It sounds like you want a WCF service, which will let you run either as a web application under IIS -OR- as a self-hosted Windows service. There is a bit of a learning curve if you've never done WCF, but it is well worth learning.

WCF under IIS, you get the same benefits as you get with running any web site. Application lifecycle management, maintenance using the IIS mms plug-in, running under a specific pool identity, etc.

As a Windows Service, you manage through the Services mms, and you have to manually write a little more code (just a little) to handle the service startup and shutdown, and of course you don't get the application lifecycle management that you do with IIS.

Which you choose may depend on how much security access you have to the server, and which tools you are allowed to run. If you have full access to the server, I prefer the IIS way, but that's totally subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Service vs Web Service is apples vs oranges... A windows service doesn't serve up data on its own...

So here are some options:

**Data Access in traditional Code**

It sounds like this is what you have.  As long as this is a logically separate layer, this probably isn't too bad.

**Services**

Using services has a lot of advantages such true separation of concerns / implementation.  You can even have your service implemented in a different language / platform than your client app.  A downside might be performance.  You're likely going to have to serialize / deserialize data and that takes cpu cycles any way you slice it.

**Interface Driven Approach**

This is nice because you can write your data access in your application against an interface.  That interface can be implemented by "traditional" ADO / ORM code.  Or you can consume a web service.  This has the distinct advantage of separating the UI from data and making automated unit testing much easier.